# How to have my computer go to sleep after a scheduled task ONLY if the computer was woken up by the task in the first place

Tags: command-line, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

*Using Windows Task Scheduler*

I have a task I want to run at 5:30 PM Daily, but I'm not sure if I'll be on that computer at the time of the task.

So, I want to allow Windows to wake my computer to run the task. The issue is, I do not want my computer awake if I'm not using it.

My question is: Can I have windows put my computer to sleep after it completes a task **only** if it was woken up by the task, but allows it to stay awake if the computer was already awake?

I'm sure I could use `powercfg -lastwake`, but I'm not sure how to read the output to check

I'm using a batch file for this task as well, if that's relevant

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE

I have figured out a way to do this with pretty minimal awake time. Since I know the execution time of my script down to a narrow range (Give or take 20-30 seconds for my longest-running script), I have created a batch file with a PowerShell script to put my computer to sleep while allowing other wake-up timers. I have put this batch file on task scheduler, scheduling them around 6-7 minutes after my task normally finishes, and making the task require my computer to be idle for 5 minutes. Although I may have some tiny mishaps with this script, I should be good for the most part, and 5 minutes is plenty of time to ensure my computer does not accidentally sleep on me.

Here is the batch file code (found online somewhere):
`powershell.exe -command "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::SetSuspendState([System.Windows.Forms.PowerState]::Suspend, $false, $false)`

I have removed some of the XML file bit for the scheduled task, but here is some of the XML code you can use to do something similar:

```
-<Settings>
<MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
<DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
<StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
<AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
<StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
<RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
-<IdleSettings>
<Duration>PT5M</Duration>
<WaitTimeout>PT0S</WaitTimeout>
<StopOnIdleEnd>false</StopOnIdleEnd>
<RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
</IdleSettings>
<AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
<Enabled>true</Enabled>
<Hidden>false</Hidden>
<RunOnlyIfIdle>true</RunOnlyIfIdle>
<DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
<UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>true</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
<WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
<ExecutionTimeLimit>PT72H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
<Priority>7</Priority>
</Settings>
```